# can not push file into sdcard in android

Tags: android

permission of sdcard is d--- how can we change the permission of sdcard to read particular file into sdcard ?

Answer (score 0):

inside menifest tag of menifest file add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i can not push file into sdcard error is that Read only file system in output of console like

Comment: i can not push file into sdcard error is that Read only file system in output of console like fail to install file in sdcard and null(item)

Answer (score 0):

What does "read particular file into sdcard" mean? Are you trying to read a file, or write a file to the SD Card. As @Sunil says, you must have your permissions set if you are trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

First you check the emulator.

Go to Window-->Android virtual Device manager-->Edit->Hardware->new->SD Card support-->yes.

Next, check the permission.

Select DDMS-->File Explorer-->mnt-->sdcard (Check permissions)
If permission is d---------.

Next you start the command prompt.
ctrl+r ==> then write some commands to Command prompt.

```
adb shell

su

mount -o rw,remount rootfs /

chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard
```

That's all