# android:Read only file system error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

[image]

how can i push file on the sdcard..
permission of sdcard is d---
i deleted old avd and created new one but have the same problem
i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231752/can-not-push-file-into-sdcard-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061227/how-to-push-file-from-pc-to-sdcard-in-android-mobile-using-abd-push-command) too but still facing the same problem..
i enter inside android-sdk/tools and used the command mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Create new AVD and give **SIZE** like **1024** MiB like below. I think this will work for you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In adb shell,try command like that:

```
mount -o remount rw /
```

I think that can help you.
^-^